# jQuery to pull a specific div from a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm working on a Tampermonkey script that pulls data from another page, while the code MOSTLY works, it's returning the full page, not just a specific section where the data I need is contained. The data I need is within a table, obviously within an html page. I myself am fully new to javascript/jquery, but have a partner with extensive knowledge on the matter. He's stuck on this as well, as normally, we could utilize other types of data culling, but this is within an organization-specific toolset (tampermonkey included)

```
// GET request. Returns the json response text in the callback function
const httpGetReq = async (targetURL, callback) => {
    GM.xmlHttpRequest({
        method: "GET",
        url: targetURL,
        responseType: "text",
        onload: response => {
            callback(response);
        },
        onerror: response => {
            console.log('Failed GET!');
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
};
```

```
$("#Find").click(function() {
    httpGetReq(url, res => {
        $('body *').not('#the_table_filter, #the_table_filter *').remove();
        if (res) {
            // Safely paste IP in here to an html element
            myList.value='some ip value';
            console.log(res);
        }
});
```

These are what I understand to be the areas where I need to be working with, but could be wrong. We're trying to find a way, without having to open the other page, to just narrow down the jquery search into that "the_table_filter" table section of the body.
First post here, so I apologize for being all over the place. I'm willing to update with info needed, just didn't know the best "first impressions" that would be needed. For simplicity sake, the TM script is running from "Homepage" and trying to get data from "Stations" page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will first need to use the [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse the HTML string from your request. You can then pass this to jQuery and then you can do whatever you need to with jQuery object.

So for example, the below example will make a request to JSFiddle and retrieve the logo...

https://jsfiddle.net/ta4fxrog/

This snippet of code is the important part...

```js
// Create a new parser instance and pass our html string.
const parser = new DOMParser();
const html = parser.parseFromString(response, 'text/html');

// Create a jQuery instance of the parsed html.
const $doc = $(html);

// Extract our element.
const $logo = $doc.find('#no-war');

// Add the extracted logo our result element.
$target.append($logo);
```

And in context to the question...

```js
$("#Find").click(function() {
    httpGetReq(url, res => {
        $('body *').not('#the_table_filter, #the_table_filter *').remove();
        if (res) {
            const parser = new DOMParser();
            const html = parser.parseFromString(res, 'text/html');
            const $doc = $(html);

            // Extract content and add to DOM...
        }
});
```

Note that there are few things to be aware of...

1. Any content on the requested page added with javascript will not be retrievable this way.
2. Your requests need the proper Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) headers.

Comment: I appreciate this so much. It makes sense for sure (also, I can't express how much I appreciate the context part you added) and I've been adding it in. I'll see if i get it to fire properly, but it looks like some reading on my part (which is great) to identify better for my situation how to implement it.